# Androi studio No me deja emular la aplicación

Tags: android-studio

La app la podía lanzar bien en el emulador pero conforme ingrese algo no me permite alzarla más.

Este es el error:

> --------- beginning of crash
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.smartconstruction, PID: 2913
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smartconstruction/com.example.smartconstruction.Home.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.smartconstruction. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.smartconstruction. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
>           at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at com.example.smartconstruction.Home.HomeActivity.setupFirebaseAuth(HomeActivity.java:113)
>           at com.example.smartconstruction.Home.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:44)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>   Application terminated.

Answer (score 1):

El problema se describe aquí:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not
>   initialized in this process com.example.smartconstruction. Make sure
>   to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Estas usando `Firebase` y no estas inicializando esta clase, para inicializar antes de usar esta clase usa:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

---

Lo puedes realizar dentro del método `onCreate()` de tu `Activity`, ejemplo:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    //Inicializa Firebase.
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); 
    ...
    ...

    }
}
```

Comment: @CristianArce inicializa con FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); antes de usar la clase.

Comment: perfecto si me funciono, pero ahora como hago con el resto del codigo para firebase?? ahora solo me da problemas para cargar el profile

Comment: Cuando se encuentra inicializado Firebase puedes hacer uso de sus métodos, ¿a que te refieres con el profile?

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar y guarde esta respuesta espero te sirva.

1. Descargue la exptencion  en `file/settings`
2. Descargar la nueva versión de `genymotion` y buscar la ruta del SDK

Tenga en cuenta que el número de versión del NDK puede variar. Por ejemplo, en lugar de `android-ndk-r13b`, podría ser una versión anterior como `android-ndk-r10e`.

Para establecer la ubicación del SDK de Android, ingrese la ruta completa del directorio del SDK de Android en el cuadro Ubicación del SDK de Android. Puede navegar a la ubicación del SDK de Android en el Explorador de archivos, copiar la ruta desde la barra de direcciones y pegarla en el cuadro Ubicación del SDK de Android.

Por ejemplo, si su ubicación de Android SDK está en `C: \ Users \ username \ AppData \ Local \ Android \ Sdk`, borre la ruta anterior en el cuadro Ubicación de Android SDK, pegue esta ruta y haga clic en Aceptar.

Ahora si te sigue apareciendo error de compilación android estudio, error `runtask`:

1. Eliminar de forma segura la build carpeta del directorio de la aplicación.
2. En Android Studio, `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`
3. `Build -> Clean Project Entonces Build -> Rebuild Project`.

Así que la build carpeta será regenerada y espero que el error se haya ido.

Esta información la guarde hace algún tiempo espero te funcione.

Comment: muchas gracias lo voy a intentar